# How to draw this circle instead of Bresenham's Circle Algorithm

Tags: visual-c++

```
int main()
{
    const auto console = ::GetConsoleWindow();
    const auto context = ::GetDC(console);
    constexpr auto red = RGB(255, 0, 0);
    constexpr auto yellow = RGB(255, 255, 0);

    RECT rectClient, rectWindow;
    GetClientRect(console, &rectClient);
    GetWindowRect(console, &rectWindow);
    int posx, posy;
    posx = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) / 2 - (rectWindow.right - rectWindow.left) / 2;
    posy = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) / 2 - (rectWindow.bottom - rectWindow.top) / 2;

    const int radius = 150;
        for (int y = -radius; y <= radius; y++)
            for (int x = -radius; x <= radius; x++)
                if (x * x + y * y <= radius * radius)
                    SetPixel(context, posx + x, posy + y, red);
}
```

It gives me this result [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1m6BM.png)

it looks good but i saw this weird pixels at sides (up, down, right, left)
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtTv7.png)

and this is what I want (I added some pixels at the top so it looks better)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1gTX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your "what I want" looks anti-aliased.  So draw anti-aliased.

If the original condition is not met, but `x*x + y*y <= (radius+1)*(radius+1)` is met then you need a partially-shaded pixel.

Another way to do anti-aliasing is to test not the center of each pixel but the four corners (x \plusminus 0.5, y \plusminus 0.5).  If more than zero but fewer than four corners are inside the circle, you need a partially-shaded pixel.

Comment: Voight can you please show it in code ? I dont know how you mean it